# Data Written to Plist is not saving

Tags: objective-c, plist

I made a few changes to the plist like inserting,deleting and reordering rows in a table.plist is changing to default on viewDidDisappear.

I tried the following code.

```
-(NSString *)dataFilePath{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dataFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ETCategoryList.plist"];
return dataFile;
}


//Code for deleting.
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){
    [[self categoriesArray]removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSArray *indexPathsToRemove = [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath];
    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathsToRemove withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    [tableView reloadData];
    NSArray *revisedArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:self.categoriesArray];
    [revisedArray writeToFile:[self dataFilePath]  atomically:YES];
}
}
```

Comment: Show the code where you trying to save to plist

Comment: @AnoopVaidya It's the last line of the posted code.

Comment: What kind of objects are in the array?

Comment: Side note - don't call `reloadData` after calling `removeRowsAtIndexPaths:`. Do one or the other, not both.

Comment: its an array of dictionaries.with name and image.

Comment: @Chandu That's the problem. You can't store `UIImage` objects in a plist without first converting them to `NSData`. Read the docs for the `NSArray writeToFile:atomically:` method. Images should be written to the file system anyway. You could store just the filename in the plist.

Comment: But I am storing it as a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is :

```
NSArray *revisedArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:self.categoriesArray];
[revisedArray writeToFile:[self dataFilePath]  atomically:YES];
```

which is correct!!!

The problem should be from `self.categoriesArray`, if the array contains some objects/ custom object then you can not write directly.

You need to archive it to NSData

```
NSData *objData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object];
```

---

Or you can endcode it in your Custom Class.

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:obj1 forKey:@"key1"];
    [encoder encodeFloat:obj2 forKey:@"key2"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    obj1 = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"key1"];
    obj2 = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"key2"];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Actually, there is no need to create `revisedArray`. Simply call `writeToFile` on `self.categoriesArray`.

Answer (score 0):

your code is fine enough. its working well with me.
Sample code:

```
self.clickMeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
       for(int i =1; i<10;i++)
    {
    [self.clickMeArray addObject:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"n%d",i] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"iN%d",i]]];
    }
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dataFile = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyName.plist"];
    [self.clickMeArray writeToFile:dataFile  atomically:YES];
```

try to clean Build and Relaunch.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UIBarButtonItem *lefttBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                            target:self action:@selector(EditTable:)];
[[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:lefttBtn];
[lefttBtn release];
 }
- (void) EditTable:(id)sender
 {
if(self.editing)
{
    [super setEditing:NO animated:NO];
    [table setEditing:NO animated:NO];
    [table reloadData];
    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Edit"];
    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain];
}
else
{
    [super setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    [table setEditing:YES animated:YES];
    [table reloadData];
    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTitle:@"Done"];
    [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone];
}
}

 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){

 [[self categoriesArray]removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 [[self categoriesArray] writeToFile:[self dataFilePath]  atomically:YES];
 [tableView reloadData];
}
```

}

Comment: How does removing the `dataFilePath` method make any difference? It's still the same code.